# Suppose I have a topological space $X$. Let $Y\subseteq X$ be a subspace. If $S$ is a connected subset of $Y$, then $S$ is a connected subset of $X$?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Suppose I have a topological space $X$. Let $Y\subseteq X$ be a subspace.
Is it true that if $S$ is a connected subset of $Y$, then $S$ is a connected subset of $X$? The definition I have for connectedness is the clopen one, i.e. a topological space $Z$ is connected iff the only clopen sets are $\emptyset$ and $Z$. I used this to prove a theorem, but if it doesn't hold then clearly my proof of said theorem doesn't hold. As such, I'm wondering if it's true, and if so how to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true, since determinin whether a topological space $S$ is connected only depends upon the topology of $S$. And the topolgy that $X$ induces in $S$ is equal to the topology that $Y$ induces in $S$.

Comment: This is a nice way to think about this, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.